# IE + placeholder

Tags: jquery, javascript

Использую placeholder ко всем инпутам, но один небезызвестный браузер не понимает html5. Решил применить костыль, но при написании столкнулся с проблемой т.к. абсолютно все инпуты подгружаются с помощью ajax. И что-то у меня никак не получается привязать к появлению элемента, с помощью live() функцию. Следующий вариант отказывается работать:

```
$("input").live('load',function(){});
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. И еще один вопрос: есть какой-нибудь event срабатывающий на любой ajax ответ?

**UPD:** Кое-что получается, но не могу допилить до конца, при возврате к измененному значению в инпуте код срабатывает, как будто внутри плейсхолдер:

```
   if ($.browser.msie){              
          $(document).bind("ajaxComplete",function(){
              $("input[placeholder]").each(function(index,e){
                  if ($(this).attr("isPlaceHolder")===undefined){
                      $(e).val($(e).attr("placeholder"));
                      $(e).attr("isPlaceHolder",true);
                  }
              }).focusin(function(){                    
                  if ($(this).attr("isPlaceHolder")){
                      $(this).val("");              
                  }
              }).focusout(function(){    
                  document.title=$(this).attr("isPlaceHolder");
                  if ($(this).val()!==""){
                       $(this).attr("isPlaceHolder",false);
                  }
                  else{
                      $(this).val($(this).attr("placeholder"));
                  } 
              });
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Так как Вы используете jQuery, то, возможно, стоит воспользоваться готовым решением - https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder .

Плагин очень маленький - 2,7Кб в минифицированном виде, и достаточно популярен (более 1300 форков). Если браузер нативно поддерживает плейсхолдеры, то плагин просто не активируется.
Ну, и от многих багов, которые Вы или не найдете или обнаружите не сразу, будете избавлены.

Answer (score 0):

Увы и ах, придется каждому ajax-запросу в callback-функции прописывать что-то вроде `$('input[placeholder]').focusout();` или выводить их сразу заполненными.

**Добавлено**

```
$('input[placeholder]').live('focusin', function(){
    if(this.value == this.getAttribute('placeholder')){
        this.value = "";
    }
}).live('focusout', function(){
    if(this.value == ""){
        this.value = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
    }
});
$('body').ajaxComplete(function(){
    $('input[placeholder]').focusout();
});
```

Comment: А вот это работает - > $(document).bind("ajaxComplete",function(){alert('AjaxComplete');});

Comment: Тоже хороший вариант. =)

Comment: Обновил ответ.

Comment: @ling .Пятница, мозг умер. Почему в моем коде не срабатывает это  
if ($(this).attr("isPlaceHolder")){$(this).val("");} ???

Comment: Кстати, твой ответ не предусматривает, что делать если пользователь наберет, то же самое, что содержит плэйсхолдер))

Comment: >Почему в моем коде не срабатывает это
А у this есть атрибут isPlaceHolder?

>если пользователь наберет, то же самое
Значит, пользователь совсем глупый. Ну, отправит данные так, без редактирования - все равно там значение уже подставлено.

Comment: Я предпологал, что у меня уже помутнение разума, и вызвал алерт, который показал, что attr("isPlaceHolder",true) действительно создает такой атрибут. Кстати у меня в вопросе даже выведен не затертый дебаг document.title=$(this).attr("isPlaceHolder"); И он показывает, что все ОК.